# Mysql blob image display in UiImage swift 3

Tags: ios, mysql, uiimageview, blob, swift3

I have a database with images stored as blobs and would like to display them in a UiImage. I am able to get the data into my app as a JSON feed and I am able to grab the image data (via print) as follows

`[["image": <UIImage: 0x14ea397b0> size {750, 750} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]]`

I have no idea how I translate this data back into the UIImage I have on my storyboard

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have blob data as a string from db. you can convert it to image as bellow.

```
let imageBytes = "" // blob data
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let imgData = imageBytes.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
    }
}
```